# Rename files to unicode name in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, unicode

How do I rename files to a unicode name(Persian) in C/C++? calling `rename()` in Linux renames files properly, but in Windows, files gets a name like *Ø³Ù„Ø§*. after rename.

Comment: Have you tried using _wrename()?

Comment: How are you determining that the file names in Windows are incorrect?

Comment: Linux traditionally uses UTF-8. Windows uses UTF-16. Unless you stick to the common subset, things are going to differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To properly rename files in Windows, you may want to try using the (non-standard) [**`_wrename()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f.aspx) CRT function.

Note that Windows uses Unicode **UTF-16** as its default Unicode encoding. So, in general, when passing Unicode strings to Win32 APIs or CRT functions like the aforementioned one, you should use the UTF-16 encoding.